How do CAMM2, (R)DIMM, (C)UDIMM, and (C)SODIMM (S)DRAM differ?
With the recent advent of CAMM2 to replace SODIMM:

CAMM2 was designed to replace SODIMM and is better than DIMM so it is picking up speed for desktops.

...and CUDIMM to replace DIMM:

CUDIMM is designed to replace DIMM, and will be better for higher density applications, like servers and workstations with 8+ DIMM slots.

...one might think that one merely replaces the other on laptops, whereas the other does so on desktops. However, CAMM2 is on some desktop motherboards, and servers use RDIMM, which may or may not change:

Servers and workstations will continue to use RDIMMs.

Consequently, does a comprehensive list of the differences exist, so that a consumer can choose between them? If not, can anyone provide one?
I don't know how broad of a question this is, so a summary is acceptable if it's unanswerable otherwise.

Perhaps this would be better asked at ServerFault?
